# Checking if a user is logged in from site master file

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

When users log in, their sessions are set like so:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["LoggedIn"] = true;
HttpContext.Current.Session["FullName"] = (string)Reader["FirstName"] + " " + (string)Reader["LastName"];
```

My `Site.master` file contains a navigation menu that's site-wide, and I'd like to change it to show different links depending on if the user is logged in or not.

Something like this in `Site.master`:

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
    <% 
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["LoggedIn"] != null)
        {
            %><li><a href="/user74/aspnet/Logout.aspx">Log out</a></li><%
        }
        else
        {
            %>
                <li><a href="/user74/aspnet/Register.aspx">Register</a></li>
                <li><a href="/user74/aspnet/Login.aspx">Log in</a></li>
            <%
        }
    %>
    </ul>
</div>
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. Looks like you can't use ASP tags like PHP tags.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you considered making the hyperlink a server-side control and updating it's NavigationUrl and text in the Master.cs?

Comment: "However, this doesn't seem to work. Looks like you can't use ASP tags like PHP tags." - I don't see an error in this code. Unless my brain is shutting down for the night, perhaps your problem is elsewhere. Why do you say that it "doesn't seem to work"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are more in to PHP,For starters I recommend you go for the normal .NET process

1.Write HTML in aspx page,replace HTML 'a' with asp:linkbutton ,likr

```
<div id="navigation">
 <ul>
  <li><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" PostBackUrl="/user74/aspnet/Logout.aspx">Log out</asp:LinkButton></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

2.Write codes in pagename.aspx.cs page,in your case write session checks in page_load event

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["LoggedIn"] != null)
    {
        LinkButton1.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good point. I believe you can also turn the `<li>` elements into server-side controls by adding `id="LogoutLinkListItem" runat="server"` so that you can set the Visible property of those to false, just in case that is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In the first place, I would advice you to use [ASP.NET Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa291347%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to authenticate the users instead of using Session. This gives numerous benefits such as Role based security etc.

You can authenticate the users against

- Windows (default)
- Forms
- Passport

Once you use one of these authentication methods, you can use the `LoginView` control to render different HTML for different set of users. For more information you can see [ASP.NET Tip: Using the LoginView Control](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/security/article.php/c13127/ASPNET-Tip-Using-the-LoginView-Control.htm)